# How can I promote bicycles.stackexchange on a "Promote cycling" day?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In a couple of months, various bicycle organisations throughout Australia are running a national [Ride to Work Day](https://www.bicyclenetwork.com.au/general/ride2work/93176/).

I've ridden on this day a number of times and it's a pretty big event. There are multiple free breakfasts provided at various locations, as well as a number of breakfasts/events run by organisations and corporations for their own internal staff and customers.

The main presence is a festival in the city, where they have many stands from bicycle brands, community groups and various road authorities.

I'd like to try to promote our site somehow. Does anyone have any advice on the best way to do this? I could get some business card styled cards printed, or maybe some stickers. Any other suggestions?

Comment: We can probably talk SE into *sending* you stickers, t-shirts, water bottles and/or business cards. I don't think they have any bikes.SE specific stickers or t-shirts, so those would just be "Stack Exchange" branded. The water bottles are pretty nice.

Comment: That's interesting @freiheit. Who should I talk to about that?

Comment: I just found this answer http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/643/1588 which has information about requesting 'swag', which I've filled out

Comment: ... and this question has some useful links to flyer content and layout http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/562/1588

Answer (score 1):

That type of event is perfect for items such as flyers, business cards or even water bottles branded with the site URL and either a short elevator pitch, or an example question.

How about an A5 flyer given to everyone at one or more of the breakfast stops, with Benefits of Cycling to Work as a headline, and then perhaps excerpts and links to questions such as:

- [Safety guidelines for cycling in traffic](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/722/2077)
- [Reasons for and against wearing helmets](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1678/2077)
- [Mandatory bike lights...](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/3866/2077)

Possibly even have a QR code for the site so people can scan it on their smartphones...

If you can articulate requirements and cost, you may be able to request funding from Stack Exchange to help cover it.

Comment: Good idea. Who did the site design? Was it @samthebrand? I might need some help with the art, but this could be very useful collateral.

Comment: it was @Jin, see http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/404/2077. Also have a look at this question on promotional materials: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/643/2077

Comment: Except the "Do Mandatory Bike Lights at Point of Sale Save Lives?" question has a score of -4, so it might not be the best question to highlight. :) But there are a bunch of other good questions with the "commuter" tag.

Comment: Yeah- sorry, I literally grabbed a few as examples. Bound to be ankle to find better ones with a wider search.